# How can i collect data from form with javascript and store it in variables?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, collect

Hey lets say i have a simple form like this:

```
<form>
<label for="name">Enter name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name">
<label for="surname">Enter surname:</label>
<input type="text" id="surname">
<label for="number">Phone number:</label>
<input type="text" id="number">
</form>
```

and in javascript, instead of getting values one by one and storing them with queryselectors, is there a way i can select the whole form and get its input values? also after that how can i store them in variables so i can use them later? for example, print them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData#examples):

```js
let myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
let formData = new FormData(myForm);
console.log(formData.entries());
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <label for="name">Enter name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <label for="surname">Enter surname:</label>
  <input type="text" id="surname">
  <label for="number">Phone number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="number">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bobi. You may use javascript FormData() method.

```
var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'))
```

Please check this document.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

Hope this helps. Happy coding~ :)